# Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module

Tags: module, dependencies

window11
gulp-cli 2.3.0
gulp 4.0.2

tsconfig.json -------
...

```
"compilerOptions": {
          "target": "es2016",  
          "module": "ES2015", 
          "baseUrl": "./", 
          "sourceMap": true, 
          "esModuleInterop": true,
          "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
          "strict": true, 
          "skipLibCheck": true 
}
```

test.ts ------------------

```
import hello from './components/utils.js'
```

typescript was bundling

Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module './components/utils.js' from 'D:\newtech\mvoting\mvoting\src\ts\test.ts' required by D:\newtech\mvoting\mvoting\src\ts\test.ts

file
ts
-components
|   utils.ts
| test.ts

1. why didn't it find utils.ts
2. Before this question, I tried to use jQuery in typescript, but there was a resolve issue, so I tried for over 10 hours, and then gave up. Of course, I used @types/jquery, and I used a lot of different methods. I also installed and deleted modules. And tsconfig.json also tried to change it. So I gave up using jQuery and just tried to use typescript, but this problem happened, so is gulf and typescript not compatible? Or maybe I'm having a problem with typescript. Why is the setting so difficult in gulp?